# Smoothing sparsely sampled signal

Tags: filtering

I am looking for a method to smooth a very sparsely sampled signal, which is shown below. Digital filters did not work very well, because for achieving an acceptable smoothness of the offset, the peak (which is very important) gets smoothed significantly as well. I've tried different methods: fit with stretched exponentials, fit with polynomial, wavelets. Applying a fit with two stretched exponentials has shown the best results, however I´m not quite there yet. Can someone point out other methods? Thanks!
[image: Sampled Signal]

Comment: What part of the signal in your question requires something doing to it. What is that "something" that you need doing? At the moment you hold all the cards.

Comment: Also, I would recommend that you formally accept answers to previous questions that you see as having relevant answers. If there's something in an answer that prevents you from doing so then raise a comment and ask for clarification. Formal acceptance can be regarded as "the fee" you pay for getting good information.

Comment: Does it have to be a Hardware filter? Otherwise RBF composition might help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function

Comment: What's wrong with that trace? It looks fine to me. I notice the peak is made up of two straight lines. Is that not acceptable? Would a parabolic curve fit through the peak and two adjacent be acceptable? Are you looking for smoothing, which by definition moves data points around, or interpolation, a smooth curve that goes through all existing data points? Obviously the two are mutually exclusive.

Comment: You may want to create a filter where the degree of smoothing applied to each point is inversely proportional to the local average derivative, such that it smooths significantly less where the signal is changing rapidly like at the peak.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that curve fitting would be the most promising method for your problem, but instead of trying some random model functions (polynomials, wavelets, ...) that probably don't have anything to do with the physical reality of the thing you are measuring you should use a model function that you can expect to do well, i.e. choose one that is backed by a theoretical model that describes your setup.

As long as you don't tell *what* you are actually measuring you can't expect much more help here.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the result you desire, there are several ways to 'smooth' this data. First off, smoothing isn't a good term to use. Smoothing means you want to reduce the noise and find an average value, by the way your question is worded it looks like you want to do other things so I'll give a basic coverage of all.

1) Interpolation
If you want to increase the resolution of your data, Interpolate the signal for even sampling. Most math packages have an interp function that allows you to resample the data to create even sampling or increase the resolution of your data. Interpolating doesn't really do anything for noise, it just gives you more data to play with or you can resample with even samples for filtering (filtering assumes an even sampling rate)

2) [Curve fitting](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingExponential.html)
Lets say you have an exponential data, you can fit a model \$ y = e^{xc_1+c_2}\$ to it and then the data is as 'smooth' as you want. It can be described as 'drawing a line' through the data.

[image]

The problem with this is you need a model that will fit your data. The data shown is kind of like an exponetial, it looks like a gaussian function with a constant.

$$ f(x) = e^{\frac{(x-c_1)^2}{c_2}}$$

You could change the shape of the model by adding parameters

$$ f(x) = e^{\frac{(x-c_1)^2+c_3}{c_2}}+c_4$$

another thing that might help is if you take the log of the data it can help you find the 'shape' of the data if it were not an exponential. For example:

\$ log(y) = log(e^{xc_1+c_2}) = x*c_1+c_2 \$

which is just a line. An exponential function is just a line, if the same transform is applied to your data you might see a polynomial. These are just suggestions. Some other models that might work are integrated exponential models but those are harder to fit. Depending on what your data is there already might be a paper or article with a model. Most packages have curve fitting functions like nonlinear least squares which in essence adjust the parameters to mimimize the error between the two functions. It can be difficult with some models to find the right minimum, which is also dependent on the initial conditions given to the function.

If there is no function that exists that can fit your data, you can fit it by parts. The data after the 'hill' is a reversed exponential with an offset

$$ y = e^{-x*c_1}+c_2$$

The 'hill' could be fit with a gaussian, a polynomial or other shapes.

3) Filtering
There are a few filters that also might be interesing to try:
[Savitzky Golay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter) filters can are great for smoothing data, just get the window size and filter order right (3 should work).
Median filters also smooth data in certain instances. 
There are also other statistical smoothing filters depending on the package that you have.

Another thing with filters is sometimes the edges get filltered, to overcome this you can pad the data on each side and then truncate it after filtering.